# Wedderburn Artin theorem and module category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I am reading "An Introduction to Homological Algebra" by Rotman. In the chapter about adjoint functor, he says "The Wedderburn–Artin theorems can be better understood in the context of determining those abstract categories that are isomorphic to module categories."

I am currently doing a course about representative theory so that I can understand the W.A. theorem, at least its statement, and also some elementary category theory such as limits, colimits and adjoint functors. Can anyone briefly explain what Rotman is talking about?

Comment: Isn't that what the next few pages (up to the exercises) do?